# Need a next post button for blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, blogspot

I am working on a blog and wanted to add a next post button somewhere between every post like this website. http://www.damnlol.com/

In the website, you can see a blue button through which you can go to next or previous post. I tried creating something similar to my blog @ http://viralonlineimages.blogspot.com/2011/11/invisible-man.html but nothing worked. Is there any way to add the button there?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which can place an image at the position:

Add `position: relative;` to your **#main-wrapper** div.
Add `position: absolute; top: 45px; z-index:999` to **#blog-pager span** (You'll need to create this)
Add `left: 0;` to **#blog-pager-newer-link**
Add `right: 0` to **#blog-pager-older-link**

```
#main-wrapper {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 5px;
    float: left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#blogger-pager span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 999;
}

#blog-pager-newer-link {
    left: 0;
}

#blog-pager-older-link {
    right: 0;
}
```

You can use negative values for `left` ad=nd `right` properties too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I did not understand it. Can you make it a bit more clear please.